# ASCII and Binary Trees

Tags: python, ascii, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm suppose to write a program that reads an input file and an output file, it reads the characters from the input file (only consisting of lower case) and writes out the ASCII code of each character as binary strings to the output file. I've previously had a binary tree class and it works fine so I'm supposed to construct a binary tree that contains each lowercase letter in the position specified by their ASCII code. Then, I need to read in another input file and output file that uses a binary tree that I've come up with. It should read in the binary string in the input file and convert the string back into the corresponding sequences of characters, and then write the characters into the output file. I have my code here, it clears out my input text and writes nothing onto the output files.

```
from binary_tree import BinaryTree

def asciify(input_filename,output_filename):

    input_file = open(input_filename)
    cnt = input_file.read()
    output_file = open(output_filename,'w')
    for line in cnt:
        for char in line:
            if (ord(char) > 96 and ord(char) < 123) or ord(char) == 32 or ord(char) == 10:  
                asc = ord(char)    
                binary = bin(asc) 
                binary = binary[2:]
                output_file.write(binary)
    input_file.close()
    output_file.close()

def alphabet_binTree():

    tree = BinaryTree()
    for letter in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ' ', "\n"]:
        tree.add(letter,bin(ord(letter))[2:])       
    return tree

def alphabet_writer(input_filename,output_filename):

    input_file = open(input_filename)
    output_file = open(output_filename,'w')
    tree = alphabet_binTree()
    for line in input_file:
        tmp = ''
        for char in line:
            tmp = tmp + str(char)                       
            if tmp == str(bin(ord('\n'))[2:]):           
                output_file.write(tree.get(tmp))
                tmp = ''                                
            elif tmp == str(bin(ord(' '))[2:]):        
                output_file.write(tree.get(tmp))
                tmp = ''
            elif len(tmp) == 7:                         
                output_file.write(str(tree.get(tmp)))
                tmp = ''
    input_file.close()
    output_file.close()

def main():
try:
    input_filename = input("Enter the input file: ")
    output_filename = input("Enter the output file: ")
    asciify(input_filename,output_filename)
    alphabet_writer(output_filename,input_filename)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Input file does not exist.")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to know what's wrong in the code that doesn't do what I need it to do.

Comment: You should mention in the question what it is exactly that doesn't work, what you have tried,...

Comment: It's at the end of the statement where I said it clears the input text and prints nothing onto the output file.

Comment: You have 2 output files, which one are you talking about ?

Comment: Could you show how you are using these functions (i.e. in what order)?

Comment: @Alex I've changed the code above, adding the main function, this is the order of code... sorry for the ambiguity

Comment: Your asciify code works as expected, so it's probably somewhere in the alphabet_writer/alphabet_binTree functions that something goes wrong.